# How logical AND (&&) works in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, logical-operators

I faced a scenario to check null reference for both the outer and inner objects. There is a chance of outer object may null and inner object too.

```
 if (outerObject != null && outerObject.innerObject != null)
 {
    outerObject.innerObject.DoSomething();
 }
```

If the second expression in ***if*** evaluated then *NullRefence Exception* will be thrown.

I have an option to go with nested if like

```
if(outerObject != null)
{
    if(outerObject.innerObject != null)
    {
        outerObject.innerObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I just want to know, Whether or not the second expression will be evaluated even if the first expression is false?

Which one is the Best?

Comment: Fish or fowl, the code generation for the 1st snippet is completely identical to the 2nd snippet.  Called [short-circuit evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx).  The vast number of programmers favor the 1st snippet, it is up to you to discuss it with your team members or make your own choice.

Comment: CSharp uses [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so the second comparison is done only when necessary.

Comment: It's so basic and I believe it is mentioned in any book (have you read one?). Moreover it's so easy to test, write several methods returning `bool` and play with them (returning `false` or `true`) while using condition like `if(Method1() && Method2() && (Method3() || Method4())) ...`

Comment: It's not about && operator. It's about how IF statement works. Spam.

Comment: @ZverevEugene I think that this is about &&, not how IF works. What if the code would be `var compRes = outerObject != null && outerObject.innerObject != null`? Would it throw exception? No, so that is definetly about && operator

Comment: @codroipo I stand corrected, what I meant is the question is not about && in particular but about all the boolean operators.

Comment: @ZverevEugene I disagree, the question is at most about logical operators, boolean operators (as of [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691309(v=vs.71).aspx)) contains also & operator, | operator, ^ operator...
If your code looks like `outerObject != null & outerObject.innerObject != null` (note the usage of & boolean operator instead of &&) you will have exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` operator works by checking the first operator/expression - if evaluates to true, only then the second is considered.

So, your first option is enough:

```
if (outerObject != null && outerObject.innerObject != null)
 {
    outerObject.innerObject.DoSomething();
 }
```

Comment: Just a note, in most books this type of evaluation is called "short-circuit" evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

C# 6.0 now supports `?.` Null Conditional Operator. That means you can transform:

```
if (outerObject != null && outerObject.innerObject != null)
```

to

```
if (outerObject?.innerObject != null)
```

Also, && uses short-circuit evaluation in C#, it first checks the left/first expression then (if its true) the right one.

Comment: It's not `Lazy` it's a short circuit!

Comment: @CallumLinington edited

Comment: If you wish to bring in the Null Conditional Operator then do it to the end. The code should look like:

outerObject?.innerObject?.DoSomething(); No `if` statement required.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, both are equal. Interestingly compiler may transform he second code into first style `if` statement. You can also simply do this:

```
outerObject?.innerObject?.DoSomething();
```

Comment: The code should be in C# 5.0

Answer (score 2):

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)

If the first expression is false it never will check for the second!

So your first option is good:

```
if (outerObject != null && outerObject.innerObject != null)
 {
    outerObject.innerObject.DoSomething();
 }
```

This is also known as [short-circuit](https://www.tradingcode.net/csharp/operators/short-circuit-evaluation/) evaluation